# hide Bing Maps AJAX v7 DirectionsManager infoboxes

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using for first time the DirectionsManager to create routes in Bing Maps AJAX v7. The route is created correctly, but comes with two small "infoboxes" showing "A" at the start of the route, and "B" at the final. I want to remove those infoboxes, but honestly, after reading all the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312832.aspx) and "Binging/Googling" a while, I can't found anything helpful. Also, I tried every option inside setRenderOptions. Any ideas?

```
        directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
        directionsManager.resetDirections();
        directionsManager.setRenderOptions({autoDisplayDisambiguation: false, 
            autoUpdateMapView: true, displayManeuverIcons: false, displayPreItineraryItemHints: false, displayPostItineraryItemHints: false, displayRouteSelector: false, displayStepWarnings: false, drivingPolylineOptions: { strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(150, 255, 51, 51), strokeThickness: 8 }
        });

        directionsManager.setRequestOptions({ routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving });

        var seattleWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: '000 fake street, Houston TX 77000' });
        directionsManager.addWaypoint(seattleWaypoint);
        var tacomaWaypoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: '111 fake street, Houston TX 77111' });
        directionsManager.addWaypoint(tacomaWaypoint);

        directionsManager.calculateDirections();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to customize the pushpin to display blank pushpin with a small size (I've tried with another pushpin with 15x15 pixels size):

```
// Set the render options
            directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ 
                itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('itineraryDiv'), 
                displayWalkingWarning: false, 
                walkingPolylineOptions:{strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(200, 0, 255, 0)},
                waypointPushpinOptions: {icon:'pin_blank.png', height:1, width:1}
            });
```

The other way might consist in calling the service by yourself and handling the request and response in your code. Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427607.aspx

Here is the code that might be what you will help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map = null;

         function GetMap()
         {
            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),{credentials:"Your Bing Maps Key", mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road }); 


         }

         function ClickRoute(credentials)
         {

            map.getCredentials(MakeRouteRequest);
         }


         function MakeRouteRequest(credentials)
         {
            var routeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.0=" + document.getElementById('txtStart').value + "&wp.1=" + document.getElementById('txtEnd').value + "&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&jsonp=RouteCallback&key=" + credentials;

            CallRestService(routeRequest);

         }


          function RouteCallback(result) {


             if (result &&
                   result.resourceSets &&
                   result.resourceSets.length > 0 &&
                   result.resourceSets[0].resources &&
                   result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) {

                     // Set the map view
                     var bbox = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].bbox;
                     var viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[0], bbox[1]), new Microsoft.Maps.Location(bbox[2], bbox[3]));
                     map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries});


                     // Draw the route
                     var routeline = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].routePath.line;
                     var routepoints = new Array();

                     for (var i = 0; i < routeline.coordinates.length; i++) {

                         routepoints[i]=new Microsoft.Maps.Location(routeline.coordinates[i][0], routeline.coordinates[i][1]);
                     }


                     // Draw the route on the map
                     var routeshape = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(routepoints, {strokeColor:new Microsoft.Maps.Color(200,0,0,200)});
                     map.entities.push(routeshape);

                 }
         }


         function CallRestService(request) 
         {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("src", request);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
      <input id="txtStart" type="text" value="Seattle"/>
      <input id="txtEnd" type="text" value="Portland"/>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate Route" onclick="ClickRoute()"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nicolas. I made an empty png and I replaced my setRenderOptions with: directionsManager.setRenderOptions({waypointPushpinOptions: { icon: 'images/blank.png', height: 2, width: 2 }, drivingPolylineOptions: { strokeColor: new Microsoft.Maps.Color(150, 255, 51, 51), strokeThickness: 8 }  but in the start point still shows an "A", and in the end point shows the "infobox" with a "B", but this time the B is outside of the box. I'll try with the second option...